# I want to populate the company name automatically in the "view/jobs/_form.html.erb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

company name should populate automatically in the job views form

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :company
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :company_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :c_name
      t.text :c_description
      t.integer:user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# Models
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :companies
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to:user
  has_many:jobs

end

# Jobs controller
def show
  end

  def new

    @job = current_user.jobs.build       
  end

  def create
    job_attrs = jobs_params.except(:company)
    job_attrs[:company] = Company.find_by(id: jobs_params[:company])
    @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_attrs)

    if @job.save
      flash[:success]= "success"
      redirect_to @job

      else

      flash[:error]=@job.errors.full_messages
      render "new"
      end
    end

    def jobs_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :company, :category_id, :image,:jobclosedate,:company_id)
    end
```

in views/jobs/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job,validation:true ,html: { mutlipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Job Title", input_html: { class: "form-control"}%>
    <%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description", input_html: { class: "form-control" }%>
    <%= f.input :company, label: "Your Company", input_html: { class: "form-control" }%>
```

company name should populate automatically in the views/jobs/_form.html.erb, it will not automatically populate and it, when I was trying to create a job, it will not get the company name automatically, could you please help me to figure out this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
job_attrs[:company] = Company.find_by(id: jobs_params[:company])
```

to

```
job_attrs[:company] = Company.find_by(id: jobs_params[:company_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a nested form. Please take a look over [simple_form Associations](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations)

How it should look (probably need to tweak it yourself)

`views/jobs/_form`

```
= f.simple_fields_for :company do |company_fields|
  = company_fields.input :c_name, label: "Your Company", input_html: { class: "form-control" }
```

`JobsController`

```
 def create       
   @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)
   if @job.save
   .....
 end

 def jobs_params
   params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :company, :category_id, :image,:jobclosedate,company_attributes: [:id, :c_name])
 end
```

`Job Model`

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
```

Comment: there are having a error  /PC/Desktop/Ruby/Jobs_board2/app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:57: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end C:/Users/Anuradha-
              
  def jobs_params
   params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :company, :category_id, :image,:jobclosedate,:company_attributes:[:id, :c_name])
  end

  def find_job

Comment: @AnuradhaWithanage I don't know exactly what you did. Check line 57. What I wrote above is to guide you through. You did not close an `end`.

Comment: thanks for supporting me, but still it's saying company must exist

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a job under a company which companies created by this user which user need to create a job then you need to collection_of_select dropdown that makes easier to select company, like below

```
<%= f.input :company_id, :collection: current_user.companies, label_method: :c_name, value_method: :id, label: "Company", include_blank: false %>
```

If current_user create one or multiple companies then all companies will be populated to the drop-down form.

You need to add `company_id` to the job creation strong parameters.